# Is there any way to make wordpress website look smaller?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I developed my wordpress site with elementor page builder, and from the beginning I had the desktop zoomed out for 90%. And now when I finished my work and started looking at it from other devices I noticed it looking too big and clumsy.
   Is there any way to make the website look smaller from the source code ? It would look much cleaner this way, but it's too complicated to edit every font element from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Yay, found something

```css
   html { 
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); 
        transform-origin: 50% 0;
        zoom: 0.8; 
        zoom: 80%; 
    }
```